# How to call three get methods in one controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api-routing

Hi I am developing webapi application and I have three GET methods in one controller. I am able to call 2 methods but third one I am not able to call.

Below are my methods I am able to call.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("me")]
public HttpResponseMessage me()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Get me");
}
URL:http://localhost:22045/api/user/me

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getUser(int id)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Get user");
}

URL: http://localhost:22045/api/user/1
```

I am not able to call below one.

```
[Route("user/{role}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string role)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Get me on role");
}
```

I want to call it like

```
http://localhost:22045/api/user/OptionalRoleParameter
```

May I get some help here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using attribute routes with route constraints should help differentiate the routes enough to avoid clashes

First ensure that attribute routing is enabled.

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Then make sure that the controller has the necessary attribute

```
[RoutePrefix("api/user")]
public class UsersController : ApiController {

    //GET api/user/me
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("me")]
    public HttpResponseMessage me() {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Get me");
    }

    //GET api/user/1
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int")] // NOTE the parameter constraint
    public HttpResponseMessage getUser(int id) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Get user");
    }   

    //GET api/user
    //GET api/user/OptionalRoleHere
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{role?}")] //NOTE the question mark used to identify optional parameter
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string role = null) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Get me on role");
    }
}
```

Source: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2 : Route Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints)

Answer (score 3):

> Optional route parameter as `string`

```
[Route("user/{role?}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string role)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Get me on role");
}
```

You can't have `string` as an optional parameter because it's not supported as a nullable constraint in **Web API**, see this for more info, [Route Constraints in Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way ti fix this?

Comment: You can write a custom route constraint.. an example is available in the link I have given in the answer